# Flurry Bottom banner ads not displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ads, flurry

I have used Flurry ads and integrated Flurry bottom ads from following link
https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/publisher/code/ios/

**when I integrated, Its working good. Please check**
[image: ads coming in device]

**Now I that application is live and its give me following error.**

**errorDescription : Error Domain=FlurryAds Code=117 "FlurryAds: Ad request to server failed." UserInfo=0x17dc62c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=FlurryAds: Ad request to server failed.}**

**adError : 1**

Comment: @V.K. : you find any solution?.because right now i phase same issue.

Comment: This error was solved by updating Flurry SDK.

Comment: @VishalKhatri You find any solution for your question ?

Comment: @DaxeshNagar U find any solution for `Error Domain=FlurryAds Code=117 "FlurryAds: Ad request to server failed." UserInfo=0x17dc62c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=FlurryAds: Ad request to server failed.}` this error ?

Comment: Yes, Update the SDK and Check Flurry Account settings.